# Doubt on integrating $f$ on a given region .

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I was asked to integrate the following function:

> $f(x,y,z)=1-z^2$ on $U$
>    where $U$ is a pyramid with the top vertex $(0,0,1)$ and base vertices :$(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,0), (1,1,0)$

the hint said that :
the cross section of given pyramid at fixed value $z$ is square : $$[0,1-z]\times[0,1-z]$$

but I can't understand how is it so..kindly help ..

Comment: I think you forgot to mention that the top vertex is $(0,0,1)$?

Comment: @karakusc sorry for that .I'll edit it..

Comment: @ScipioAemilianus please don't waste reviewer time by making unhelpful edits that don't improve the post quality. In particular, don't fix irrelevant meta commentary and "thanks"-type sections, *just get rid of them!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: find the four lines determined by the top vertex and each base vertex. Find the intersection of each line with the plane $z=$constant.